# Convert BIGINT to hexadecimal (string) in MonetDB

Tags: number-formatting

I have a column of type `BIGINT` in my MonetDB database and for readability I'd like to print its contents as hexadecimal number when executing a `SELECT`statement. Is there any way to achieve this?

I read through the MonetDB documentation, looking for a function such as `HEX()`, `CONV()` etc. but could not find anything like that (or close). I even read through the defined functions (`SELECT name FROM sys.functions;`) with no luck.

P.S. I'm not allowed to create the tag *monetdb* here due to lack of reputation. Could someone please add this tag for me? (This is quite annoying since I am forced to select a tag on none of the existing seems appropriate to me here…)

Comment: Try casting it as a BLOB. According to the [documentation](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/BuiltinTypes), the BLOB object is an unbounded byte string.

Comment: Do you have a hint on how to get a `BLOB` from a `BIGINT` column? `CAST()` and `CONVERT()` do not seem to work:
`SELECT CONVERT(CAST(1 AS bigint), blob);` returns `types bigint(64,0) and blob(0,0) are not equal`.

Comment: I wouldn't try casting at all.

Comment: Maybe I got your comment "Try casting it as a BLOB" wrong. What would you recommend then, given that the column is in BIGINT format.

Comment: In SQL Server, there's an implicit conversion by saying (for example) `DECLARE @var AS VARBINARY(MAX)` and then just assigning the a BIGINT to that makes it into binary with `SELECT @var = <bigint_value>`.